# What is laughing wisdom and swift wisdom?

Tags: pali-canon, wisdom

From [SN 55.24](https://suttacentral.net/sn55.24/en/sujato), I found the terms "laughing wisdom" and "swift wisdom". What do they mean?

> They have laughing wisdom and swift wisdom, and are endowed with
>   freedom.
>   *hāsapañño javanapañño vimuttiyā ca samannāgato.*

Comment: I'm guessing this means they see the humour and irony of our situation and are realised to the point they may act and speak (or not act and speak) spontaneously and reliably from truth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Footnotes 50 and 51 from Piya Tan's [analysis of SN 55.24](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/3.6-Sarakani-S-1-s55.24-piya.pdf):

> 50. Of joyous wisdom,” hāsa,pañña, alt tr “of laughing wisdom” (from hasa, “laughter, mirth, joy”). “Here one
>       with much joy [laughter], mirth, contentment and gladness perfects the virtues: this is joyous wisdom” (Pm 21.17/
>       2:199 f). Comys mention hāsa,paā (joyous wisdom), javana,paā (quick wisdom) [see foll n], tikkha,paā
>       (sharp wisdom, which cuts off all defilements) and nibbedhika,paā (penetrating wisdom, by which one maintains
>       dispassion toward all formations) (DA 3:391-393, 4:84-86; MA 4:84; SA 1:120-123, 2:85 f; AA 2:85; ThaA 3:106 f;
>       NmA 1:231 f; cf PmA 3:640 on hasa,paā)
> 51. “Of quick wisdom,” javana,pañña. This refers to one who quickly understands that the 5 aggregates are all impermanent, suffering and non-self (Pm 21.18/2:200). See prev n.

"Pm" is the *Patisambhidā Magga*.